# In SQL Mgmt Studio I can run a query from object explorer but no from the design window

Tags: sql

In SQL Mgmt explorer 2008 against a 2008 database, when I right click a view and click select top 1000 rows everything works.  I can even change it to view all rows by deleting the "TOP 1000" and re-executing the view.
But, when I right click the view and click design and then execute the view, it has an execution error with a bunch of multi-part identifier could not be founds.
It is a fairly complicated query that has many joins.

It has been working for many years and is still working.  But i need to edit the query and it won't let me design and test it.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In the TOP Left of management studio you should have a drop down list with all the databases. 
Is the correct database selected?